# Integration of a general 1-dimension form of cylinder thermodynamics

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I'm not sure on how to integrate this equation twice.

$$
\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
\left( \frac{r \partial T}{\partial r} \right) +
\frac{e}{k} = 0
$$

After integrating twice the outcome is:
$$
 T(r) = -\frac{e}{4k} r^{2} + c_{1} \ln r + c_{2}
$$

Where $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are constants. After integrating it once it will give the rate of conduction heat transfer.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome and thanks for posting to Mathematics StackExchange! This MathJax tutorial and the edits will help you continue to contribute: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Try with this $$d \left( \frac{r \partial T}{\partial r} \right) = -\frac{e}{k} r \, d r$$

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick didn't realise you could bring the stuff in front of the brackets to the other side of the equal sign.